# uploading image file to server

Tags: android, mysql, image

I try to find way to send picture from android gallery to online database server such as mySQL , but I think I should upload this IMAGE file first  to server after that getting the direct image link and send this link  to database mysql

any one have simple idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example encode the image in Base64, and then send it to your backend parsed as JSON via rest webservices, and store it in a BLOB field.

Comment: this is complected idea , i want simple ways , i don't have much time